# How do I fix a main menu that is not working?

Tags: theme

I access CiviCRM and the dashboard is missing. The menu items don't work.

Things tried

- delete files/civicrm/templates_c/*
- read ConfigAndLog. No errors reported
- cv flush
- cv upgrade:db
- cv ext:upgrade-db (or /civicrm/upgrade?reset=1)
- civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend?reset=1. Reset paths, cleanup caches
- check domain in civicrm.settings.php
- check browser console for files that aren't being loaded (nothing reported)
- review resource urls civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1
- check system status civicrm/a#/status (still dies)

How did I get here?

- update to drupal 9
- update civicrm

All updated via composer and *git push composer.lock*. There is a git hook

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/srv/$t/$s git checkout -f $b
export COMPOSER_COMPILE=all
(cd /srv/$t/$s && composer install --no-dev)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main symptom is that there are no files in the libraries directory.

```
> ls web/libraries/civicrm/packages
_ORIGINAL_


> composer civicrm:publish
Publishing CiviCRM assets to web/libraries/civicrm
Generating CiviCRM asset map
```

Fixed.